# symfony2 the target-entity OC\PlateformBundle\Entity\Image cannot be found in 'OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert#image

Tags: symfony

I can't find the solution of the problem when I do the update : the target-entity OC\PlateformBundle\Entity\Image cannot be found in 'OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert#image'.

The Advert.php :

```
<?php

namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Advert
*
* @ORM\Table(name="oc_advert")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\AdvertRepository")
*/
class Advert
{
public function __construct()
{
// Par défaut, la date de l'annonce est la date d'aujourd'hui
    $this->date = new \Datetime();
}
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist"})
*/
private $image;

public function getImage()
{
 return $this->image;
}
public function setImage(Image $image = null)
{
  $this->image = $image;
}

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
 */
private $date;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $author;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
 */
private $content;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set date
 *
 * @param \DateTime $date
 *
 * @return Advert
 */
public function setDate($date)
{
    $this->date = $date;

    return $this;
}

/**
* Get date
*
* @return \DateTime
*/
public function getDate()
{
    return $this->date;
}

/**
* Set title
*
* @param string $title
*
* @return Advert
*/
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
* Get title
*
* @return string
*/
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
* Set author
*
* @param string $author
*
* @return Advert
*/
public function setAuthor($author)
{
    $this->author = $author;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get author
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthor()
{
    return $this->author;
}

/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 *
 * @return Advert
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
* Get content
*
* @return string
*/
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}
/**
* @ORM\Column(name="published", type="boolean")
*/
private $published = true;

/**
* Set published
*
* @param boolean $published
*
* @return Advert
*/
public function setPublished($published)
{
    $this->published = $published;

    return $this;
}

/**
* Get published
*
* @return boolean
*/
public function getPublished()
{
    return $this->published;
}
}
```

I have looked for any uppercase ou lowercase problem... but none noticed.

Comment: You've spelt `Platform` wrong...  `OC\Plat-->e<--formBundle\Entity\Image`.

Comment: No, the bundle is always written like this without the e, it is just a wrong typing in my message. The correct error message is :  the target-entity OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image cannot be found in 'OC\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert#image'.

Comment: The problem was on the extension of the file of the entity